# Why wrap an IO result in IO Monad

Tags: haskell, monads

In Haskell we have a function `readFile :: FilePath -> IO String`. My question while understanding monad is why wrap it in `IO`? Couldn't we just have written function like these:

```
(lines.readFile) path
```

Rather than

```
(readFile >>= lines) path
```

What benefit does the IO wrapper provide?

Comment: That would make the language impure. If we allow arbitrary I/O actions in pure code then the function `f :: Int -> Int` could overwrite the whole harddisk when called. By forcing I/O only inside the IO monad we have the guarantee that `f` *cannot* overwrite the harddisk when called.

Comment: Are you suggesting that `readFile :: FilePath -> String` (in which case `readFile` would be impure), or are you suggesting that `.` be polymorphic enough to include the type `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> IO b) -> a -> IO c`?

Comment: I recommend not thinking of `IO` as a "wrapper".  You probably don't think of `Tree` as a "wrapper" around `a` in `Tree a`.

Answer (score 7):

Haskell expressions are [referentially transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency). This means that if `readFile` would really have a type of `FilePath -> String`, then expression `readFile "a.txt"` would always yield the same result. Even if you read the file, then change it, and then read again, you will get the contents in its first state.

Thus, we need to distingush between **values** and **actions**, and this is what `IO` is for. It doesn't let you use the result `readFile "a.exe"` in other expressions until you **perform** an action associated with it. As a consequence, after changing your file you **have to perform** the reading action again, to get file contents, and because of that you will able to see the changes.

Comment: The [1993 paper by Peyton Jones and Wadler](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/imperative/imperative.ps) which introduced the IO monad is a good introduction and might be a worthy reference.

Comment: I don't really like the wording of this answer... you are stating that because expressions are referentially transparent, then `readFile "a.txt"` would always return the same result... this sounds pretty wrong from a language design point of view. The language was *designed* to avoid I/O actions in expressions *in order to obtain* referential transparency... I mean: referential transparency is *not* "the cause", it's the objective achieved by forcing I/O into the IO monad. Haskell *could* have been designed how the OP wanted, but then it would not be referentially transparent.

Comment: Yes, it is an important note that the language was deliberately designed this way, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

### We write functions that create computer programs

It should be noted that Haskell is a functional programming language. Functions, in the mathematical sense, always produce the same values for the same inputs.

Now this requirement to always produce the same result constrains things quite a bit, since a function to read a file would somehow have to produce the same result every time, even if the file was later changed. That's obviously not what we really want.

There is, however, a way to make a functional programming language that can handle reading a changing file. What you do is to write a function that produces some action the computer should perform. So you might perform an action composed of the following steps:

```
Read the file
Break it into lines
Change the even-numbered lines to uppercase
Output the lines to the screen
```

These four actions aren't performed yet. They're just a sequence of actions that we might perform. A function can return that exact same sequence of potential actions every time it's called, which makes it a proper mathematical function.

The `main :: IO a` function in Haskell returns the action that the program should perform. It always returns the same action, making it a proper mathematical function. When the program is run, the computer evaluates the `main` function, producing the action the computer should perform, and the computer then executes the action.

### Do notation

Do notation takes the strangeness out of the process, giving you the feel of a much more standard programming language. You have three options:

1. Perform an action and do nothing with its results
2. Perform an action and store its results
3. Process data using only functions (no actions)

These are done in the following ways, respectively:

1. `action args`
2. `result <- action args`
3. `let result = f . g . h . whateverCalculation $ value`

This is similar to an imperative language like C where you do, respectively:

1. `action(args);`
2. `result = action(args);`
3. `result = f(g(h(whateverCalculation(value))));`

Comment: `main` is not a function. Its type has no arrows in it.

Comment: @dfeuer What *is* `main`?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer It is a value of type `IO a`. If you want a more vivid description, it is a *program*, in the sense explained by the answers here. (Saying that a value of type `IO a` is a program is no different than saying e.g. a value of type `[a]` is a list.)

Answer (score 2):

For `(lines.readFile) path` to work, the type of `readFile` would need to be `FilePath -> String`. That, however, doesn't make sense in Haskell. A Haskell function is supposed to always produce the same results when given the same arguments. If the result type `readFile` was `String`, however, that would not happen, as `readFile "foo.txt"` would have to, for any useful implementation of such a `readFile`, produce different strings depending on the contents of the *foo.txt* file.

The Haskell solution to this issue is giving `readFile` the type `FilePath -> IO String`. An `IO String` is not a string, but a *program* that can be executed by the computer and that, when executed, somehow materialises a `String` into memory. While the `String` thus produced might be different each time the program is executed, the program itself remains the same, and therefore `readFile` always returns the same results when given the same arguments (and so, for instance, `readFile "foo.txt"` is always the same program).

This trick of manipulating a program that produces an I/O-dependent result instead of the result itself only works if the I/O-dependent result is kept opaque; that is, if there is no way of directly extracting it. In other words, there cannot be, for instance, an `IO String -> String` function -- for one, it would allow us to implement a `readFile` with the inappropriate type `FilePath -> String` that we have discussed above. There are, however, indirect ways of using the I/O-dependent result that do not lead to trouble. One of them is using it to create a second program, whose I/O-dependent result is just as opaque as the first one was. The `Monad` interface allows us to express this usage pattern:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Specialising `(>>=)` to `IO`, we get:

```
(>>=) @IO :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
```

The first program has type `IO a`, and the function that produces the second program using the I/O-dependent result of the first one has type `a -> IO b`. The result of `(>>=)` is a program which executes the first program and the second, newly generated, one in sequence. For instance...

```
readFile "foo.txt" >>= putStrLn
```

... is a program which reads the contents of *foo.txt* and then displays these contents.

---

P.S.: With respect to your example involving `lines`, it is worth noting that both `(readFile >>= lines) path`, as you have written it,  and `(\p -> readFile p >>= lines) path` are rejected by the type checker. Something that does work is:

```
(fmap lines . readFile) path
```

In it, we are making indirect use of the file contents in a different way. If we have a program which produces an I/O-dependent result, we can turn it into a program which produces a modified version of this result. That is done through `fmap`, from the `Functor` class:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Or, specialising to `IO`:

```
fmap @IO :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b
```